# How to print a returned tuple in another method

Tags: python, return, tuples

If I have two methods:

1. one is a method that changes a `string` into a `tuple` and returns it.
2. other method prints out the `tuple` returned.

At the end how would I do this?

Input would be something like `"12345 firstName lastName otherInfo"`.

```
def information(sentence):
    splitUp = sentence.split(' ')
    return sentence

def printAsString():
    "".join(sentence)
    print(sentence)
```

Comment: Could you provide the input and expected output?

Comment: Have you tried passing an argument to `printAsString`? Your `information` function already takes an argument, so you know how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. But what is your objective? This code is kind of pointless...

```
def information(sentence):
    '''Splits the sentence on space and returns it as tuple'''
    split_up = tuple(sentence.split(' '))
    return split_up

def print_as_string():
    '''Prints tuple as string'''
    sentence = "welcome to SO dear friend"
    print(" ".join(information(sentence)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_as_string()
```

Comment: Good example of proper [Python coding style](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1):

It would be

```
print ''.join(employeeInfo)
```

But my question is where on earth did employeeInfo came form?